# How to make single ParseObject calls using two file uploads

Tags: android, parse-platform

```
    final ParseFile parseFile1 = new ParseFile("poll_image1.jpg",scaleImage("poll_image1",imageList.get(contestImage1.getId())));
                        final ParseFile parseFile2 = new ParseFile("poll_image2.jpg",scaleImage("poll_image2",imageList.get(contestImage2.getId())));

                        parseFile1.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException arg0) {

                                parseFile2.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseException arg0) {
                                        ParseObject jobApplication = new ParseObject("Poll");
                                        jobApplication.put("poll_question", contestQuestion.getText().toString());
                                        jobApplication.put("poll_type_id", 1);
                                        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                                        jobApplication.put("user", currentUser);
                                        jobApplication.put("parseFile1", parseFile1);
                                        jobApplication.put("parseFile2", parseFile2);
                                        jobApplication.saveInBackground();

                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Poll Created !!", 1000).show();

                                        contestQuestion.setText("");
                                        contestImage1.setImageResource(R.drawable.photo_add);
                                        contestImage2.setImageResource(R.drawable.photo_add);
                                        category.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.choose_a_category));

                                        mProgressHUD.dismiss();
                                    }

                                }, new ProgressCallback() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void done(Integer arg0) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }, new ProgressCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void done(Integer arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });
```

I implemented the above code, by saving ParseObject only after saving Two files using the ParseFile. It makes 3 server calls, But I want it in only 1 server call. Because of the 3 calls to server, it takes lot of time to upload and to save the parseobject.

Comment: are you unable to run threads on your client? You can use a connection pool and simple shotgun multiple calls as long as there are not cross-dependency issues among the calls. Look at thread pool client and async Posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only option would be to create a Cloud Function that accepts the two byte arrays and the other fields, then it would internally do the 3 calls needed.

Because the 3 calls are being done between two Parse servers it could potentially be quicker than your current code.

You can find out more about Cloud Functions in the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions).

Comment: I am getting "parseconsole.exe is not valid win32 application" message when i launch parseconsole.exe. I am using Winxp sp2 . How to fix it.

Comment: Ok. I able to successfully test "Hello" function from command prompt using Parse.exe. But how to implement above image upload code ? Give me an example ?

Comment: Look at https://parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#images where it shows code that manipulates an image. You can see where it can make a HTTP request for image data and load it, or create a `Parse.File` using base64 encoded data.

Comment: I am newbie on parse. If anybody can convert my Question code into Parse Cloud code. It will be really helpful. This one is important on my current project, This may take some time to do so I moved to other task. I will come to this later.

Answer (score 0):

63 pngs uploaded to parse.com by a multithread client in 3 Seconds...

[Details](https://www.parse.com/questions/rest-api-or-android-sdk-for-real-time-messaging-and-data)